# Transfering SD cards to new phone

Tags: sd-card

My girlfriend and I both bought "Optimus V" phones at the same time with the same carrier,I have since upgraded but her phone is starting to act possessed by demons. Is it possible to just change out the SD card in my phone with hers and have the carrier transfer my old phone to her number?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to swap the SD cards yes and all of the data will be fine, as for changing the number try just moving her SIM card over to your old phone, if the phone's not locked to a network then it should just work.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the SIM card over was the step I forgot.

Comment: @brett No problem! If this sorted your problem then you should accept the answer by pressing the tick to the left.